# Delphi + TidSMTP.Connect + Socket Error 10054 - Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: delphi, connection, reset, peer

I have a Delphi application which uses TidSMTP to send emails, well is supposed to. When tested on our local mail server it works fine but as soon as I set it up to work with the external mail server I get the socket error 10054 - Connection Reset by Peer when it trys to perfrom the l_idSMTP.connect line of code

I have setup the account I wish to use to send emails in Outlook on the same machine and it is able to successfully send emails so I am not sure why the Delphi application on the same machine is not?

Below is my code

```
    try
      l_pConfigurator := TConfigurator.Create;
      l_idSMTP.Username := l_pConfigurator.SMTPUser;
      l_idSMTP.Password := l_pConfigurator.SMTPPass;
      l_idSMTP.Host     := l_pConfigurator.SMTPHost;
      l_idSMTP.Port     := strtoint(l_pConfigurator.SMTPPort);
      if l_pConfigurator.SMTPAuth = 'LOGIN' then
      begin
        l_idSMTP.AuthenticationType := atLogin;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(l_pConfigurator);
    end;

    l_idSMTP.Connect(30000);

    if l_idSMTP.Connected then 
      l_idSMTP.Send(l_idMsg);
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try to send a mail interactive from the command line using Telnet? (And are you sure that Outlook uses SMTP to talk to the server?)

Comment: Which version of Indy are you using? `Connect(30000)` looks like Indy 9. In Indy 10, use `ConnectTimeout := 30000; Connect;` instead.

Comment: Maybe your ISP/ICP is blocking TCP port 25

Comment: I will test with Telnet and try verify what Outlook is using. I configured Outlook the same way I did my application so assume it is SMTP

Comment: Yes the version I am using is Indy 9

Comment: I verified with our Network Administrator that ports 25 and 26 are open. ALso Outlook is successfull in sending using these ports